# Need help parsing a "|" seperated line from a file

Tags: c, parsing

I have to parse a file that would look something like this

```
String|OtherString|1234|0

String2|OtherString2|4321|1

...
```

So, I need to go through every line of the file and take each seperate token of each line.

```
    FILE *fp=fopen("test1.txt","r");
    int c;
    char str1[500];
    char str2[500];
    int num1=0;
    int num2;
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        fscanf(fp, "%s|%s|%d|%d", &str1[0], &str2[0], &num1, &num2);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

There's more to it, but these are the sections relevant to my question. fscanf isn't working, presumably because I've written it wrong. What's supposed to happen is that str1[500] should be set to String, in this case, str2 to OtherString, etc. It seems as though fscanf isn't doing anything, however. Would greatly appreciate some help.

EDIT: I am not adamant about using fgetc or fscanf, these are just what I have atm, I'd use anything that would let me do what I have to

Comment: Don't use scanf.  Certainly don't use it inside a `while (fgetc)` loop (unless you understand very well how fgetc and scanf interact, and how scanf deals with newlines).

Comment: But it could be that all you need to do is write `while( fscanf (...) == 4)...` instead of calling fgetc and discarding a character.

Comment: I would avoid `fgetc`... consider reading a bunch of data into a temporary buffer and  using `memchr`, `memcpy` and `memove` as required to copy the data to the data structure you desire.

Comment: Get rid of `fgetc()`. Use `"%499[^|]"` instead of `"%s"` in the `scanf()` *format* argument.

Comment: `while(fscanf(fp, " %[^|]|%[^|]|%d|%d", &str1[0], &str2[0], &num1, &num2) == 4)` is what you're after

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using scanf for well defined format parameters.

Comment: @BugSquasher Perhaps not, but it's usually faster to write a full lexer than it is to figure out the well defined format parameters!

Comment: Nice touch with ^|

Comment: @BugSquasher *There's nothing wrong with using scanf for well defined format parameters.*  IMO there are many things wrong with `scanf()`.  First, no matter how well-defined the format parameters may be, misformatted input pretty much puts the program into an unrecoverable state.  Second, `printf()`/`scanf()` processing is fundamentally broken because a format string used by `*printf()` can produce output data that the same format string can't parse if used by `scanf()`.

Comment: I'd be happier to say "There's not much wrong with using line reading (`fgets()`, `getline()`) functions and `sscanf()` parsing when the format is well defined".  One of the problems with `scanf()` and `fscanf()` is that if anything goes awry, some of the data has been consumed and some has not and it is difficult to report errors and to recover gracefully.  If the line is in memory, it can be parsed, reparsed, and reported in error message without loss of information.

Comment: @Real Name - Without you, this is all academic.  No comments from you one way or the other on this discussion to this point.  Is any of this clearing up the problem for you?  (It would be good of you to chime in.)

Answer (score 2):

*[strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* in a loop will work for you.  The following is a bare bones example, with very little error handling etc, but illustrates the concept...

```
char strArray[4][80];
char *tok = NULL;
char *dup = strdup(origLine);
int i = 0;
if(dup)
{
    tok = strtok(dup, "|\n");
    while(tok)
    {
        strcpy(strArray[i], tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, "|\n");
        i++;
    }
    free(dup);
}
```

If reading from a file, then put this loop inside another while loop that reads the file, line by line.  Functions useful for this will include *[fopen()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)*, *[fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)* and *[fclose()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fclose.htm)*.  One additional feature that should be considered for code that reads data from a file is to determine the number of records (lines) in the file to be read, and use that information to create a properly sized container with which to populate with the parsing results.  But this will be for another question.

Note:  *[fgetc()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm)* is not suggested here as it reads one `char` per loop, and would be less efficient than using `fgets()` for reading lines from a file when used in conjunction with `strtok()`.

Note also, in general, the more consistently a file is formatted in terms of number of fields, content of fields, etc. the least complicated a parser needs to be.  The inverse is also true.  The less consistently formatted input file requires a more complex parser.  For example, for human entered line data, the parser required is typically more complicated than say one used for a computer generated set of uniform lines.